# Delete from linked tables ms access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I have a `MS Access DB` that has several tables.

My main table is called `Client`, which is linked to another table called `Abonament`, among others.

Both tables share the same field named `client_id`, which contain identical id's.

Table named `Abonament` has another **field** named `data_expirarii` which contains dates.

How do I delete all the entries from both tables (`Client` & `Abonament`) based on a specific date in `data_expirarii` **field**, from the `Abonament` table?

I've managed to delete them from the `Abonament` table using the Design Wizard and subsequently deleting every entry below or equal to **1-Jun-17** (`<= 1-Jun-17`) but the client entries remain in the `Client` table. MS Access gives me a headaque.

Comment: Does the `Abonament` table have multiple records for each client which could cover different dates, some later than 1-Jun-17?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes.

Comment: So you delete the records in `Abonament` that are earlier than 1-Jun, then you want to delete the records in the `Client` table that no longer have records in `Abonament`?  I ask because some Clients may have had Abonament records deleted, but still have records that are later than 1-Jun so clients shouldn't be deleted?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes, exactly. Main goal is to delete the client, and all subsequent information, unless he has an entry after 1-jun-17. If he has, keep the client and the entry after 1-jun-17 but delete his older entries (prior to that date) - if no entries on or after 1-jun-17 - delete entirely.

Comment: I can upload the db so you can have a look how it's structured, if that helps or I could add a relationship screenshot

Comment: publish the schema and show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to delete the records from the `Abonament` table.

```
DELETE  *
FROM    Abonament
WHERE   data_expirarii<=#06/01/2017 23:59:59#
```

**Note**: the US format of the date (mm/dd/yyyy)- this format must be used.

Next any client records that no longer have any matching records in `Abonament` can be deleted.  This query will return all records from `Clients` (written on the LEFT of the join) and only those records in `Abonament` that have a matching `Client_ID` - any other record will return `NULL` in the `Abonament.Client_ID` field which are filtered for in the `WHERE` clause and deleted.

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW Clients.*
FROM    Clients LEFT JOIN Abonament ON Clients.Client_ID = Abonament.Client_ID
WHERE   Abonament.Client_ID IS NULL
```

Make sure to take a back-up of your data while testing!

Comment: Just noticed (way too late, I know) I didn't add a thank you comment, leaving (potentially) the impression that I'm unappreciative. Therefore, thank you, Darren! ^_^